# Add an row and a column around an multilinear array

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

I want to add a row and a column of 1 around an multidimensional array in C.

For the input 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 - this is how I want it to be added. Is there in C a function like append in python, or how this can be done?

[image]

The code I already have for asking the user for elements and printing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,m;
    printf("Lines: ");
    scanf("%d" , &n);
    printf("Columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    int arr[n][m];

//    Input Elements
    printf("Input array elements: \n");
    for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j<m ; j++)
        {
            printf("arr[%d][%d]=",i,j);
            scanf("%d" , &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
//    Show Elements
    for (int i=0 ; i<n+1 ; i ++) {
        for(int j=0; j<m+1; j ++) {
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: C arrays are fixed size, and can't be expanded after they are created. So you have to create the array with the larger size, i.e. `int arr[n+2][m+2];` Of course, then you need to use 1-based indexing, e.g. the 2 is indexed as `arr[1][2]`.

Comment: If you need to change an array's dimensions in run-time, then `malloc` + `realloc` is the better choice. Alternatively, allocate the array large enough to cover the worst-case scenario but only use part of it when you don't need all of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of array does not change during its lifetime.
Even though you use Variable-Length Array, word "variable" mean that the size is kept in a variable, not that the size itself is variable.

Therefore you must create a new padded array and fill it:

```
// add 2 to each dimension due to 1-element-wide strips on each side
int padded[n + 2][m + 2];

// copy data from the old array
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
    padded[i + 1][j + 1] = arr[i][j];

// fill padded area
for (int j = 0; j < m + 2; ++j)
  padded[j][0] = padded[j][m + 1] = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n + 2; ++i)
  padded[0][i] = padded[n + 1][i] = 1;
```

This code can be easily moved to a bit more generic helper function that uses VLA parameters:

```
void pad_matrix(int n, int m,
                int pad_size, int pad_val,
                int src[n][m],
                int dst[n + 2 * pad_size][m + 2 * pad_size]) {

  for (int i = 0; i < n + 2 * pad_size; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < m + 2 * pad_size; ++j) {
    // position in src
    int ii = i - pad_size;
    int jj = j - pad_size;
    if (0 <= ii && ii < n && 0 <= jj && jj < m)
      dst[i][j] = src[ii][jj];
    else
      dst[i][j] = pad_val;
  }}
}
```

Usage could be:

```
int padded[n + 2][m + 2];
pad_matrix(n, m, 1, 1, arr, padded);
```